# awk to find repeated occurrence and sum specific column

Tags: awk

what's the way to use awk  to find repeated occurrence of string from a specific column & sum the adjacent column values?
My input:

```
A B C_1 10
A B D_0 2
A B C_1 2
A B D_2 15
A B D_0 3

output should be
2 C_1 12
2 D_0 5
1 D_2 15
```

Thanks much.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
awk '
{
    a[$3]++
    b[$3]+=$4
}

END {
    for (i in a)
        print a[i], i, b[i]
}' file
```

with output:

```
2 D_0 5
2 C_1 12
1 D_2 15
```